# Python OOP Seperating a Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-requests

I currently have a class called Client that has functions to log in to a website and interact with it using python requests. However, my log in functionality is somewhat complicated. I have to visit about 10 different endpoints to collect the correct cookies just to log in. Therefore, I have 10 different functions for the log in process to gather all these cookies which is cluttering up my Client class. I'm also using an instance variable self.session for each request to automatically keep my session cookies updated to the latest request.

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def login_func1(self, url, headers):
        resp = self.session.get(url, headers=headers)

    def login_func2(self, url, headers):
        resp = self.session.get(url, headers=headers)


    def login_func3(self, url, headers):
        resp = self.session.get(url, headers=headers)


    def login_func4(self, url, headers):
        resp = self.session.get(url, headers=headers)

..........
    def login_func10(self, url, headers):
        resp = self.session.get(url, headers=headers)
        
    def login(self, url, headers, username, password):
         self.loginin_func1(url, header)
         self.loginin_func2(url, header)
         self.loginin_func3(url, header)
         self.loginin_func4(url, header)
         ......
         self.loginin_func10(url, header)
         resp = self.session.get(url, payload = {'user':username, 'password':password}, headers=headers)
         if resp.status_code == 200:
             print('Successfully logged in!')


    def get_images(self, url, headers):
        #get images code here

    def get_table_data(self, url, headers):
        #get table data code here
```

I would like to separate the log in functionality possibly into another class. I'm not sure if I should just make a separate object called LogIn and pass the self.session variable to that class, or if I should somehow make LogIn inherit from Client. But, after the LogIn class finishes logging in, I would need to go back to Client to interact with the site. I'm not sure what the best way of seperating this could would be. I was initially thinking of something like below, but not sure if inheritance would be a better , or even possible option. Thanks!

```
from login import LogIn
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def login(self, url, headers):
        self.session = LogIn(self.session).login(url, headers, username, password)
        

    def get_images(self, url, headers):
        //get images code here

    def get_table_data(self, url, headers):
        //get table data code here

class LogIn:
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session

    def login_func1(self, url, headers):
        resp = self.session.get(url, headers=headers)

    def login_func2(self, url, headers):
        resp = self.session.get(url, headers=headers)


    def login_func3(self, url, headers):
        resp = self.session.get(url, headers=headers)


    def login_func4(self, url, headers):
        resp = self.session.get(url, headers=headers)
..........
    def login_func10(self, url, headers):
        resp = self.session.get(url, headers=headers)

    def login(self, url, headers, username, password):
         self.loginin_func1(url, header)
         self.loginin_func2(url, header)
         self.loginin_func3(url, header)
         self.loginin_func4(url, header)
         ......
         self.loginin_func10(url, header)
         resp = self.session.get(url, payload = {'user':username, 'password':password}, headers=headers)
         if resp.status_code == 200:
             print('Successfully logged in!")
         return self.session
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is the difference between the login functions? From your exemplary code it looks like you are calling the same function ten times, which could be replaced by a loop.

Comment: The log in functions are sending get, or post requests to different API endpoints with slightly different headers for each request to update the session cookies.

Comment: In the code you show, you're passing exactly the same arguments to functions with exactly the same code in their body. It's hard to give you advice about how to generalize the code when we don't have more than "different API endpoints" to go on with respect to what is different between the many calls. Can you just put those arguments into a table and loop over them all, rather than having 10 different functions?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail, I'm new to stack overflow and not great at explaining myself haha. Some of those functions are post request, some are get requests, others require a response to be returned, and others have parameters for data to be passed along with the request. Again, sorry for my lack of detail. I was worried if I explained too much the question might be too long or too confusing to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of inheritance seems to be a good approach.

I would propose to let the LogIn class inherit from Session, this way you can use it to create the Session and customize it via your desired login functionality:

```py
class Client:

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = LoginSession()

    def login(self, url, headers, username, password):
        self.session.login(url, headers, username, password)


class LoginSession(requests.Session):

    def login(self, url, headers, username, password):
        self.login_func1(url, headers)
        # [...]
        self.login_func10(url, headers)
        resp = self.get(
            url, payload={"user": username, "password": password}, headers=headers
        )
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            print("Successfully logged in!")
            
    def login_func1(self, url, headers):
        resp = self.get(url, headers=headers)

    # [...]
    def login_func10(self, url, headers):
        resp = self.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: This is a really good idea, thank you! I never thought of inheriting the Session.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell exactly what differs in your various `login_funcN` functions, since you've simplified the problem a bit too much for your example. But if the only thing that needs to change between the different login efforts is the URL and headers, you might consider packing that data up separately in a data structure, rather than using separate functions for each step. The data can be stored separately from the rest of the class, and so you might not need a second class at all (just a data structure to hold the login data).

```
cookie_gathering_data = [(cookie_url1, cookie_headers1),
                         (cookie_url2, cookie_headers2),
                         ...]

class Client:
    def login(self, cookie_data, url, headers, username, password):
        for cookie_url, cookie_headers in cookie_data:
            self.session.get(cookie_url, headers=cookie_headers)
        resp = self.session.get(url, payload={'user':username, 'password':password},
                                headers=headers)
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            print('Successfully logged in!')
```

Comment: Thanks! I took your advice and was able to implement a list for the simple requests (requests that require no response to be returned and no parameters such as a CSRF token to be passed along with them, or other parameters. Just requests that update the cookies of the Session object.) and it made it a lot cleaner.

Comment: I'm curious if I could make the abstract method generalized out to requests that do need a response and data passed along. For instance,  one request will need to return the HTML response, then call a function to parse it and find the CSRF token, then pass that token along with the next request. Not sure exactly how I'd generalize that out. I'm thinking of passing a list of dicts to the abstract method (each request would be a dict with its data needed, and maybe a pointer to the CSRF parsing fuction to call it after the request).